# Websocket endpoint returns 404

Tags: jakarta-ee, http-status-code-404, java-websocket

I am new to the Java EE 7 websocket principle.

I have a Java EE 7 server deployed on Wildfly 10.

I have configured a context path and an application path.  I am able to reach the server by `http://localhost:8080/context_path/app_path/something`.

Now, I have declared a simple ServerEndpoint:

```
@Stateful
@ServerEndpoint("websockets/stream")
public class StreamServerEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StreamServerEndpoint.class);

    @Inject
    ByteBufferStore byteBufferStore;

    @Inject
    private EventListener listener;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        LOG.info("Session opened and registered");
        listener.register(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void message(Session session, ByteBuffer buffer) {
        LOG.info("Message retrieved");
        session.getUserProperties().put("buffer", buffer);
        //byteBufferStore.retrieve().ifPresent(byteBuffer -> Common.sendBuffer(session, buffer));
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
        listener.unregister(session);
    }
}
```

On the other side, I have an external Angular 2 project which should connect to the websocket, but I get error status codes: 404, 200, depending on the link.

I get 200 with this:

```
ws://localhost:8080
```

I get 404 (no handshake possible) with this:

```
ws://localhost:8080/context_path/app_path/websockets/stream
```

What can I do to reach the websocket? Apparently my URL isn't correct, or the way I programmed the server endpoint is totally wrong.

Comment: Well, 404 is not found, not no handshake possible. Can you connect to the server with a different websocket client?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the requests from different websocket clients don't reach the server.

Comment: please refer to below URL for running example

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/real-time-applications-angularjs-java-part-3/

https://coderwall.com/p/uhqeqg/html5-websocket-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the websockets aren't on at all - depending on your version of WildFly, they may need to be enabled. Try adding

```
<enable-websockets>true</enable-websockets>
```

under the `jboss-web` node of your `jboss-web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. My bad, the WebSocket was in the wrong module (ejb).. Moving the class to the web module solved it.

Comment: You mean that we could not have websocket in ejb module? and we could have it only in war module?