# Wildfly Websocket Endpoint returns 404

Tags: java, apache, websocket, wildfly, wildfly-12

I want to setup a WebSocket Connection to upload a lot of very small files (1kb-50mb) to a web-application.

My Web-App runs in Wildfly, and the rest/https based components work fine, however my Websocket connection returns 404 everytime or 200 when I try.

Here's the code for my Endpoint:

```
package com.my.package;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@ServerEndpoint("/smallfiles/socket")
public class WebsocketApi {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2356475533479775725L;
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebsocketApi.class.getName());
  private static Set<Session> clients = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());


  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session session) {
    // Set max buffer size
    session.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024 * 512);
    // Add session to the connected sessions set
    clients.add(session);
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Client " + session.getId() + " connected.");
  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose(Session session) {
    // Remove session from the connected sessions set
    clients.remove(session);
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Client " + session.getId() + " disconnected.");
  }

  @OnError
  public void onError(Throwable error) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,error.getMessage());
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void processUpload(byte[] uploadData, Session session) {
    try {
      if (session.isOpen()) {
        // Wrap a byte array into a buffer
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(uploadData);
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Receiving Data");
        //session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buf);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      try {
        session.close();
      } catch (Exception e1) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Failed to close Session. ",e1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I had the Idea that maybe this is cuased by Apache, since our Wildfly is running behind an apache which works as reverse-proxy, so I added the Websocket Endpoints in my https-gw.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName repName
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass                   /                           http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse            /                           http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPass                   /Application/               http://127.0.0.1:8080/Application/
        ProxyPassReverse            /Application/               http://127.0.0.1:8080/Application/
        ProxyPass                   /smallfiles/socket/                 ws://127.0.0.1:8080/websocket/
        ProxyPassReverse            /smallfiles/socket/                 ws://127.0.0.1:8080/websocket/
        ProxyPass                   /Application/smallfiles/socket/      ws://127.0.0.1:8080/Application/websocket/
        ProxyPassReverse            /Application/smallfiles/socket/      ws://127.0.0.1:8080/Application/websocket/

        SetEnv proxy-sendcl 10000000
        SetEnv  proxy-sendchunked

        #   Server Certificate:
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/host.net.cer

        #   Server Private Key:
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/host.net.key

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/my_ca.crt
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

However whenever I try to access the Websocket through Javascript, I get the following Problems:

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://my.server.net/")
WebSocket {url: "wss://my.server.net/", readyState: 0, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
```

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://my.application.net/' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

or

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://my.server.net/smallfiles/socket")
WebSocket {url: "wss://my.server.net/smallfiles/socket", readyState: 0, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
```

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://my.server.net/smallfiles/socket' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I also checked the [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730527/websocket-endpoint-returns-404) from User @cayz, but sadly I don't really see, what the users solution meant.

Does anyone know where I am having my blackage?

---

**EDIT:**
I also checked the wildfly logs, and wildfly registers the endpoint.

```
2020-02-04 19:33:44,647 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) UT026003: Adding annotated server endpoint class com.my.package.WebsocketApi for path /smallfiles/socket
```